# How to change lower_case_table_names for a specific MYSQL user?

Tags: mysql

I used this in my.conf but It change all user but I want to change it for specific user

```
[mysqld]
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Comment: This question needs clarification. To begin with, what are you _actually_ trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lower_case_table_names` is a server system variable, and thus cannot be set for a specific user.